# Como passar o valor do @Html.DropDownList para o controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho um modal de cadastro que recebo 2 valores, uso um AJAX para salvar as informações, porém o valor do `@Html.DropDownList` não vai para a minha Controller, o estranho é o valor da Descrição chega no controller.

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Descrição", new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Descricao, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Tipo de Cálculo", new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.DropDownList("TipoCalculo")
                    </div><br />
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {       
    //$("#AjaxPost").click(function () {
    //alert($('#TipoCalculo :selected').val())

    $("#AjaxPost").click(function () {
        var dataObject = {
            Descricao: $("#Descricao").val(),
            TipoCalculo: $('#TipoCalculo :selected').text(),
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("SalvarMilestone", "Dashboard")",
            type: "POST", 
            data: dataObject,
            dataType: "json"
        });
    });
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, recriei seu cenário e funcionou normalmente. Como está sua classe de modelo? Ela tem alguma validação para o campo TipoCalculo? Como você está populando os valores do campo TipoCalculo?

Comment: @BernardoBotelho, sim está populando...  usei o seguinte código para ver se aparecia alert informando value do combo e ele aparece normal `$("#AjaxPost").click(function () {
    //alert($('#TipoCalculo :selected').val())`

Comment: Eu vi que seu código comentado utiliza o val() para verificar o valor, mas na hora de enviar você usou o text(). Os valores do dropbox tem texto e valor?

Comment: Sim, possui os 2

Comment: Tente colocar data:{milestone:dataObject}; para passar os dados